# Como filtrar git log por trecho de código?

Tags: git

Em um repositório local, como é possível fazer a **filtragem** dos *commits* que contêm alterações em um determinado trecho de código, como uma chamada de função? E, assim, esta operação poderia ser feita com o uso de expressões regulares (*regex*)?

---

Exemplificando, um arquivo JavaScript possui uma linha, agora indesejada, que contém um `console.log(data)` para *debug*, mas a princípio **não** há uma maneira de identificar em que *commit(s)* ou linhas ela sofreu modificações, especialmente porque as mensagens não sugerem isso (inviabilizando a solução via [`--grep`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---grepltpatterngt)) e porque a parte pode ter sido deslocada para outra linha.

No último *commit*, por exemplo, `data` foi substituída por outra variável/constante:

```
* 07b3972 (HEAD -> main) Adiciona metodo somador
* 2d33ca3 Adiciona...
* ba8489e Atualiza...
* 9ef5a2e Adiciona log debugger
```

Buscava uma opção do `git log` que, a partir do modelo-exemplo anterior, retornasse os commits `9ef5a2e` e `07b3972`, considerando que somente estes alteraram o arquivo (*`--stat`* do primeiro: `arquivo.js | 1 +`) na chamada do método pesquisado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log/pt_BR) com a opção [`-S`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log/pt_BR#git-log--Slttextogt):

```
git log -S console.log
```

Também há a opção [`-G`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log/pt_BR#git-log--Gltexpresso-regulargt), que permite passar uma expressão regular para busca, em vez de uma simples string

O comando `log` também possui muitas opções úteis para formatação da saída/resultado como [`-output`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log/pt_BR#git-log---outputltarquivogt) que escreve o resultado num arquivo, filtros como [`--since`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log/pt_BR#git-log---sinceltdatagt) que limita a busca aos commits em determinada data, entre outras várias opções